# perl variable inside a string inside back ticks

Tags: string, perl, variables

I have a filename that is formated as electric_inventory_WE_20170730_195758.dat. There is a similar file created each day. The time created may vary. I need to capture the filename with today's date, not worry about the time and end with a .dat extension.

I have created a variable for today's date. I need to use this variable inside a string inside back ticks. Something like this:

```
my $today = `date "+%Y%m%d"`;

my $filename = `ls electric_inventory_WE_$today*.dat`;
```

I cannot find a way to get this variable to work inside a string inside the back ticks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not [cross post](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1196310) without telling all locations you've done so. This avoids wasting other people's time who are not on all cross-posted sites.

Answer (score 3):

That is exactly how you use a variable in backticks.

I'm not sure what the actual problem is ("*I cannot find a way to get this to work*" is not a helpful problem description), but here's my guess:

`` `date ...` `` returns a string with a trailing newline, `"\n"`, so the command you're actually running ends up being:

```
ls electric_inventory_WE_20170330
*.dat
```

A possible solution is to avoid using the shell (and external commands such as `date` and `ls`) at all:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $today = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime;
my @candidates = glob "electric_inventory_WE_$today*.dat";
if (@candidates != 1) {
    ...   # handle error: either 0 or more than 1 files were found
}
my $filename = shift @candidates;
```

Comment: +1 for "avoid using the shell." Too many people treat perl (and other languages) as glorified shell scripts when it's safer and more robust to just write a couple extra lines of code and do it internally.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all that provided information on this and I do apologize for the cross posts. Thanks to your posts, I was able to use the following to get this to work:

my $filename="electric_inventory_WE_" . $today . "*.dat";

Comment: This does nothing like what you described. This literally just assigns `"electric_inventory_WE_20170730_*.dat"` to `$filename`; it doesn't resolve to the actual filename.